# Play multiple videos,consecutivelly in the same zone AdColony

Tags: adcolony

I'm trying to implement a screen where the player plays 3 videos and gets a reward. I've created a zone in AdColony and the first ad (of the session) works ok The second one doesn't work for the remaining of the session(Remained for about 1 minute in the app).

Is there any method I can call to load the next video in the same zone or does it load automatically after a while?

I use the following code to check if there are any videos to play:

```
if ([AdColony zoneStatusForZone:@"zone_id"] == ADCOLONY_ZONE_STATUS_ACTIVE)
{
    [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"zone_id" withDelegate:self];
}
```

If I close the app after each play and get back into it, it has an ad more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is related to fill availability, as there will not always be 3 videos ready to play in succession.  Additionally, we recommend against using multiple videos for rewards, especially if a user must view them in succession, as we have found this to cause frustration among app users.

We recommend adjusting your reward to be appropriate for viewing a single video.  However, if you do still want to use multiple video views; an AdColony admin can set this in our admin settings so that the views do not have to be consecutive.  To use this option you will need to work with our Support Team at support@adcolony.com.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. I ended up creating 3 zones. The player is rewarded each time he watches a video (the reward is better each time), but he can only watch 3 videos consecutively to prevent abuse. After that there is a 6 hour period, checked server side, before he can see new videos.